# doctrine2 native query update statement

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, native

How to do a native sql query in Doctrine 2, executing an update statement?
The createNativeQuery method on EntityManager, requires a second parameter (ResultSetMapping) to be able to map the resultsets to Objects.

But when updating (or inserting, or set, or...) there is no resulset to map.
Passing null or just new ResultSetMapping(), gives an error.

Are only select queries supported for native sql?

Answer (score 15):

Essentially ditto w/ faken,

this from the [docs](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/native-sql.html):

> If you want to execute DELETE, UPDATE or INSERT statements the Native
>   SQL API cannot be used and will probably throw errors. Use
>   EntityManager#getConnection() to access the native database connection
>   and call the executeUpdate() method for these queries.

one note of use is the connection object can be retrieved from the EntityManager:

```
$conn = $entityManager->getConnection();
$rowsAffected = $conn->executeUpdate($sql, $params, $types);
```

Answer (score 2):

Update statements are usually pretty simple, so you might as well use the normal Doctrine2 way (i.e. programmatically updating entities and calling EntityManager::flush() OR using [DQL Updates](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#update-queries)).

Having said this, if you really want to use normal SQL, you could always do it like this:

1. Keep the [db connection object](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.5/class-Doctrine.DBAL.Connection.html) you get when creating a connection with Doctrine2:

   $connection = \Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection($dbConfig->toArray(),null,$evm);
2. Execute whatever SQL you want, using the available methods in the [connection](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.5/class-Doctrine.DBAL.Connection.html) object, e.g.:

   $connection->executeUpdate($sql, $params, $types);
   $connection->exec($sql);
   ...

Comment: I want to update a rank field for all of the records, based on the ordening on one of the other fields. Something like: Set @rank := 0; INSERT INTO ranked (id, rank) SELECT id, @rank := @rank+1 FROM ranked ORDER BY score DESC ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE rank = @rank; Don't think that will be possible using DQL?

Comment: That is a different question and I'm not fully understanding it with such a short comment; I suggest you open another question asking that, but offer more details. Nonetheless if you know how to do this UPDATE in SQL, you can always use the answer I provided to your original question, which will work.